# Reading from an external file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io

I've just started using node.js, and I have been looking for ways to count the number of lines in a cpp file stored on my machine (in a different directory from that of the node.js app).

I am trying just read text from a cpp file stored inside the node.js project for now, with this function: 
 `console.log(fs.readFileSync('code.cpp', 'utf8'));`

but I get this error:

> fs.js:646     return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path),
>
> stringToFlags(flags), mode);
>                    ^
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Users\Heba\WebstormProjects\wrfile\sever.cpp'
>       at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
>       at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Heba\WebstormProjects\wrfile\app.js:5:16)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Is this the right approach to the problem? if so how can I fix this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It cant locate the file as shown in the error , make sur you did enter the right path for the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the error that you get , your script cant locate the file.
make sur that `'code.cpp'` is in the same location as your script

try using `path.join(__dirname, 'code.cpp');`

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),    
    file = path.join(__dirname, 'code.cpp');

console.log(fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8'));
```